# 2 column layout with column heights that stick to the footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a basic layout with 2 columns and a footer that behaves according to the height of which column is longer.

```
<div id="holder">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"></nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left col-md-8">
                Extends with content
            </div>
            <div class="right col-md-4">
                Extends with content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        Relative behaviour when the content of either columns is long enough. Sticks to the bottom when there is not enough content. 
    </div>
```

Full code with **CSS**: http://jsfiddle.net/TNRqL/

What would be an elegant solution to make the columns with the same heights, but that also stick to the footer?

Such as: http://jsfiddle.net/xJ6Cv/ (I used min-height on left and right columns)

I found in another question a solution to make columns of the same heights regardless of which one is longer, but it doesn't make them stick to the footer.

```
.row {
    overflow: hidden;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're OK with [around 80% browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), then you can do this elegantly with the [Flexbox CSS3 module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). You define the overall page to have a minimum height, and then mark your columns as "flexing" to fill the available space. There's [a demo here](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/), though due to the nesting of your elements it won't be quite as simple.